# How to filter out glacier files with boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I'm writing a script to parse S3 buckets files, without needing to download them locally. It seems the  code works as far as it doesn't find glacier files. I'm adding an exception for now (error handling looks better in actual code, I promise), but ideally I'd like to  see if it's possible to filter glacier files out.

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import gzip
import os


try:
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = 'my_bucket'
    prefix = 'path_to_file/file_name.csv.gz'
    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=prefix)
    body = obj['Body']
    with gzip.open(body, 'rt') as gf:
        for ln in gf:
            print(ln)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I see that using AWS CLI, I can at lest sort files in the way glacier files are at the  bottom, so there must be a way to either way sort or filter them out in boto3:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query "reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))"
```

Comment: Does the file you are retrieving happen to be in glacier?

Comment: I don't know, but if that means I can't inspect them from bucket, that might be. I tried opening them with ForkLift Archive Utility and didn't work from there either. Can only download locally

Comment: Are you saying that you can download the CSV file from Amazon S3? In the S3 management console, what is displayed as the object's Storage Class? What happens if you re-upload the CSV file and try it on that file? That would override the Glacier setting.

Comment: yea I got confused. I'll change the question as  the problem wasn't related to csv, but to glacier files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using StorageClass == 'STANDARD' (vs  == 'GLACIER'):

```
bucket = 'my_bucket'
prefix = 'path/to/files/'
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
for file in response['Contents']:
    if file['StorageClass'] == 'STANDARD':
        name = file['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)
        if name[1] != '':
            file_name = name[1]
            obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=prefix + file_name)
            body = obj['Body']
            lns = []
            i = 0
            with gzip.open(body, 'rt') as gf:
                for ln in gf:
                    i += 1
                    lns.append(ln.rstrip())
                    if i == 10:
                        break
```